# Unable to run my flutter project due to errors

Tags: flutter

Getting back to a project I freeze for 1 year I am no longer enabled to run.

I get those errors, which I cannot manage to fix.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 7 in profile mode...
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/optimized_cached_image-3.0.1/lib/src/image_provider/optimized_cached_image_provider.dart:87:40: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
      OptimizedCacheImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/optimized_cached_image-3.0.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_provider_io.dart:72:55: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
      image_provider.OptimizedCacheImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) {
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/optimized_cached_image-3.0.1/lib/src/image_provider/_image_provider_io.dart:91:5: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
    DecoderCallback decode,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.6.4/lib/src/blurhash_widget.dart:205:42: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(UiImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.6.4/lib/src/blurhash_image.dart:32:48: Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(BlurHashImage key, DecoderCallback decode) => OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'.
  Future<File> create({bool recursive = false});
               ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
  Future<File> create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
               ^
../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
  Future<File> create({bool recursive = false});
```

My `pubspec.yaml` has as follows:

```
environment:
  sdk:  '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0' #">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  stacked: ^2.2.5
  http: ^0.13.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  flutter_archive: ^5.0.0
  xml: ^6.1.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  logging: ^1.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.6.5
  settings_ui: ^2.0.2
  adaptive_action_sheet: ^2.0.0
  flame: ^1.0.0-releasecandidate.13
  geolocator: ^9.0.0
  enough_ascii_art: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  enum_to_string: ^2.0.1
  flutter_map: ^1.1.1
  latlong2: ^0.8.0
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  map_launcher: ^2.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+1
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  split_view: ^3.1.0
  graphx: ^1.0.3
  simple_animations: ^4.0.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  statsfl: ^2.0.1+1
  optimized_cached_image: #^3.0.1
  i18n_extension: #^9.0.2

  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

dependency_overrides:
  intl: any

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/app.logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround by dropping `optimized_cached_image` and replace it by `cached_network_image` v3.3.0.